# The requested resource was not found on this server error while deploying Django/VueJs app on Heroku

Tags: python, django, vue.js, heroku, django-rest-framework

I have been able to deploy my django/vuejs app on heroku successfully. The Django backend uses the django rest framework to serve the api endpoints while vuejs handles the frontend. I have set up the app on Heroku, added NodeJs and Python buildpacks, and then added my config vars. However, when i try to open the app on browser, i get `Not Found. The requested resource was not found on this server.`. heroku logs --tail shows the following:

```
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956114+00:00 app[web.1]: tmp_upload_dir: None
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956114+00:00 app[web.1]: secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956115+00:00 app[web.1]: forwarded_allow_ips: ['*']
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956115+00:00 app[web.1]: accesslog: -
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956115+00:00 app[web.1]: disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956116+00:00 app[web.1]: access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956116+00:00 app[web.1]: errorlog: -
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956117+00:00 app[web.1]: loglevel: debug
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956118+00:00 app[web.1]: capture_output: False
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956118+00:00 app[web.1]: logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956119+00:00 app[web.1]: logconfig: None
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956119+00:00 app[web.1]: logconfig_dict: {}
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956119+00:00 app[web.1]: syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956120+00:00 app[web.1]: syslog: False
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956120+00:00 app[web.1]: syslog_prefix: None
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956120+00:00 app[web.1]: syslog_facility: user
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956121+00:00 app[web.1]: enable_stdio_inheritance: False
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956121+00:00 app[web.1]: statsd_host: None
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956121+00:00 app[web.1]: dogstatsd_tags:
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956122+00:00 app[web.1]: statsd_prefix:
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956122+00:00 app[web.1]: proc_name: None
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956122+00:00 app[web.1]: default_proc_name: mysite.wsgi
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956123+00:00 app[web.1]: pythonpath: mysite
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956123+00:00 app[web.1]: paste: None
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956124+00:00 app[web.1]: on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7f10994d2488>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956124+00:00 app[web.1]: on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7f10994d2598>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956125+00:00 app[web.1]: when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7f10994d26a8>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956125+00:00 app[web.1]: pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7f10994d27b8>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956125+00:00 app[web.1]: post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7f10994d28c8>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956126+00:00 app[web.1]: post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7f10994d29d8>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956126+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7f10994d2ae8>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956126+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7f10994d2bf8>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956127+00:00 app[web.1]: pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7f10994d2d08>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956127+00:00 app[web.1]: pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7f10994d2e18>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956128+00:00 app[web.1]: post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7f10994d2ea0>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956128+00:00 app[web.1]: child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7f10994ec048>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956129+00:00 app[web.1]: worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7f10994ec158>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956129+00:00 app[web.1]: nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7f10994ec268>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956130+00:00 app[web.1]: on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7f10994ec378>
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956130+00:00 app[web.1]: proxy_protocol: False
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956131+00:00 app[web.1]: proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956131+00:00 app[web.1]: keyfile: None
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956131+00:00 app[web.1]: certfile: None
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956131+00:00 app[web.1]: ssl_version: 2
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956132+00:00 app[web.1]: cert_reqs: 0
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956132+00:00 app[web.1]: ca_certs: None
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956133+00:00 app[web.1]: suppress_ragged_eofs: True
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956133+00:00 app[web.1]: do_handshake_on_connect: False
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956133+00:00 app[web.1]: ciphers: None
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956134+00:00 app[web.1]: raw_paste_global_conf: []
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956140+00:00 app[web.1]: strip_header_spaces: False
2020-08-28T07:58:53.956651+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 07:58:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-08-28T07:58:53.957358+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 07:58:53 +0000] [4] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
2020-08-28T07:58:53.957462+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 07:58:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:35680 (4)
2020-08-28T07:58:53.957603+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 07:58:53 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-08-28T07:58:53.962110+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 07:58:53 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-08-28T07:58:53.976659+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 07:58:53 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-08-28T07:58:54.051183+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 07:58:54 +0000] [4] [DEBUG] 2 workers
2020-08-28T07:58:54.631663+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-08-28T07:58:55.371826+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 08:58:55 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T07:58:55.371871+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 08:58:55 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T07:58:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-08-28T07:59:37.638418+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 08:59:37 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:01:44.632704+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:01:44 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:02:29.057508+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:02:29 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] GET /
2020-08-28T08:02:29.413965+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.226.51 - - [28/Aug/2020:09:02:29 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36"
2020-08-28T08:02:29.414337+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ejika.herokuapp.com request_id=74ea00a7-b48f-47b6-bd61-c5ae24e57232 fwd="129.205.143.223" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=358ms status=404 bytes=402 protocol=https
2020-08-28T08:02:30.176731+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:02:30 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] GET /favicon.ico
2020-08-28T08:02:30.178965+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.226.51 - - [28/Aug/2020:09:02:30 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://ejika.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36"
2020-08-28T08:02:30.179678+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ejika.herokuapp.com request_id=58a4a423-8a3b-46ca-98ce-e94ab309d561 fwd="129.205.143.223" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=402 protocol=https
2020-08-28T08:02:38.080461+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:02:38 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] GET /
2020-08-28T08:02:38.083085+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.226.51 - - [28/Aug/2020:09:02:38 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36"
2020-08-28T08:02:38.083509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ejika.herokuapp.com request_id=b287270d-130f-4755-91d2-60d4b5fe646b fwd="129.205.143.223" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=402 protocol=https
2020-08-28T08:03:51.604711+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:03:51 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:03:57.684130+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:03:57 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] GET /
2020-08-28T08:03:57.693917+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.251.11 - - [28/Aug/2020:09:03:57 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36"
2020-08-28T08:03:57.696236+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ejika.herokuapp.com request_id=15b2e9d5-15b8-4914-be77-14162b38e694 fwd="129.205.143.223" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=402 protocol=https
2020-08-28T08:05:58.639909+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:05:58 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:08:05.793569+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:08:05 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:10:12.847432+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:10:12 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:11:42.886116+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:11:42 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] GET /services
2020-08-28T08:11:43.146423+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.61.240.57 - - [28/Aug/2020:09:11:43 +0100] "GET /services HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36"
2020-08-28T08:11:43.146644+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/services" host=ejika.herokuapp.com request_id=1a7c47a0-2fc8-463c-8c18-f2a521caf5d3 fwd="129.205.143.223" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=261ms status=404 bytes=402 protocol=https
2020-08-28T08:12:19.741009+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:12:19 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:12:22.798261+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:12:22 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] GET /login
2020-08-28T08:12:22.804687+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.61.240.57 - - [28/Aug/2020:09:12:22 +0100] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36"
2020-08-28T08:12:22.805065+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=ejika.herokuapp.com request_id=5caa2a62-43ad-49d6-be8f-a577f92afc98 fwd="129.205.143.223" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=402 protocol=https
2020-08-28T08:14:26.667902+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:14:26 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:16:33.759216+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:16:33 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:18:40.682918+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:18:40 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:20:47.631325+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:20:47 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:22:54.623126+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:22:54 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:25:01.706773+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:25:01 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:27:08.627029+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:27:08 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:29:15.626468+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:29:15 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:31:22.739250+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:31:22 +0100] [10] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:33:29.727851+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:33:29 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:35:36.665915+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:35:36 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
2020-08-28T08:37:43.476112+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-08-28 09:37:43 +0100] [11] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
```

My project structure looks like this;

```
|-frontend(vuejs)
|-django
  |-media
  |-mysite
    |-__init__
    |-settings.py
    |-urls.py
    |-wsgi.py
  |-myapp
  |-db.sqlite3
  |-manage.py
|-.gitignore
|-package.json
|-Procfile
|-requirements.text
```

Any assistance on how to resolve this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All your `GET url` requests lands at ` "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179` meaning that it's not found. Have you deployed on Heroku before or are you following any method to deploy this?

Comment: I have deployed to Heroku, and d build shows successful. since it's a Django/Vue.js app, could it be that the vue.js part of the app wasn't deployed?